# SQL Server: Choosing a collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding, collation

I have an SQL Server database and I'm trying to choose the appropriate collation.

Right now, the default one is selected: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. However, this is not enough - I need to include both latin (including Č, Ć, Š...) and cyrillic characters (Ш, Ж...). Is there a character set that encompases all of these, or better, a way to enable UTF8 as collation?

Comment: SQL Server 2019 supports UTF-8. Otherwise I suggest using `nvarchar`.

Comment: @Larnu I am using SQL Server 2019, so how do I set UTF-8? It's not one of the options in the collation dropdown menu.

Comment: So does `SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE name LIKE '%UTF8%';` not return any rows? If so, you aren't using SQL Server 2019, or aren't using a database in the latest compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the SQL collations. UTF-8 is supported under the windows collations.

I.e. in your example SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS is a SQL collation, with Latin1_General_100_CI_AS being compareable. But if you look at these set of collations. There's also ones with UTF8.

For example, there's Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC_UTF8

Which is:

- Case Insensitive
- Accent Sensitive
- Kana Sensitive
- Width Sensitive
- Supplementary Character support
- Has UTF8 support

UTF8 is not present in SQL only collations. And depending on your actual Server instance version, might not be available either.

Msdn links:

- [Collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [UTF8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#utf8)